# create new pod in rooling update its takes time

Tags: kubernetes

When I update deployment from 1.2.19 to 1.2.20 it takes time to create pods after first pod.
I set minReadySeconds to 10 but
I have wait 1m to create second pod.

[image: minReadySocond]

Answer (score 1):

The min `minReadySeconds` is not for "force" the pod to be ready

> #### Min Ready Seconds
>
> `.spec.minReadySeconds` is an **optional** field that specifies the minimum number of seconds for which a newly created Pod **should be ready** without any of its containers crashing, for it to be considered available.
>
> **This defaults to 0 (the Pod will be considered available as soon as it is ready).**

---

#### How to find your problem.

I assume that the problem is elsewhere for example
- No free nodes
- No memory etc.

To find out what the is the root cause of the long startup check your cluster events

```bash
kubectl get events -n <namespace>
```

For example you should get something like this but with more details
[image]

[image]

Comment: I didn't see any problem in get events. the first pod is 1/1 READY and then I wait 1m for second pod

Comment: when I set minReadySeconds option this issue occurred. without minReadySeconds pods  created very fast.

Comment: Of course, this is why i explained it :-) That's your answer, remove it.

Comment: I don't want create very fast , I want to be a distance between them.

Comment: I see last seen is invalid for a few seconds in get event logs . mabye the issue is time